# Correct way of linking resources in spring mvc application

Tags: javascript, css, jquery-ui, jsp, spring-mvc

I am using Jquery UI in spring MVC application. I gave in my spring mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml I gave something like

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/jqueryUI/" />
```

my directory structure is as follows

[image: directory structure]

and in my jsp I referred them as

```
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>
 <%@ page session="false" %>
 <html>

<head>
<script src="/resources/external/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="/resources/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link href="/resources/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet">

<script>

    $(function() {
 alert('function called');

    $("#datepicker").datepicker();
    });
</script>

 </head>



 <body>


 <div align="center">
 <form:form action="register" method="post" commandName="productViewModel">
 <table border="0">
<tr>
    <td colspan="2" align="center"><h2>Release Registration</h2></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Product Name:</td>
    <td><form:input path="name"/></td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td>Version:</td>
    <td><form:input path="version"/></td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td>Tag Id:</td>
    <td><form:input path="tagId"/></td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td>Release Date:</td>
    <td><form:input path="releaseDate"/></td>

    <!-- Datepicker -->

   <td> <p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p></td>

</tr>

<tr>
    <td>Setup:</td>
    <td><form:input path="setup"/></td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td colspan="2" align="center"><input type="submit" value="Save" /></td>
</tr>

</table>
    </form:form>
</div>


 </body>

 </html>
```

But when I put that page is not even loading. But when I remove

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/jqueryUI/" />
```

Page loads correctly but datepicker does not work.
Basically I need to know what is the correct way of linking resources(js/css) in jsp of a spring mvc application.
Your help is kindly appreciated.

Thank You !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using tomcat then you can use [default Servlet](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/default-servlet.html) to serve the resources.

web.xml:

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/resources/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

use `c:url` to access the resource related the context root.

jsp:

```
<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>

<link rel=stylesheet href="<c:url value='/resources/jquery-ui.css'/>"
    type="text/css" />
```

Comment: Thanks Braj. That really worked with tomcat. Hope this helps for others as well.